# freeing memory to a 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, 2d

So I created a dynamically sized 2d array using the following logic:

```
int **newBoard;
newBoard = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
newBoard[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols * rows);

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    newBoard[i] = (*newBoard + cols * i);
}
```

But now I am having trouble freeing the memory I allocated. Whenever I try to I receive a "free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000007343c8 ***" error message. I am currently trying to free the memory like:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    free(newBoard[i]);
}
free(newBoard);
```

Can anyone help me out and tell me how to free this correctly??

Comment: How many calls did you make to `malloc()`?  There must be one call to `free()` for each call to `malloc()`.  How many calls to `free()` do you make?  You make two calls to `malloc()`; you make many more calls to `free()` in general (when there's more than one row).  Oops!

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
newBoard[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols * rows);
```

you are allocating a continous block of memory for `cols * rows` spaces of `int` objects.
You can only free it once using the **start of the block**, you **cannot free it at an
offset** of the start of the memory and you cannot free it multiple times, **only
once**.

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    newBoard[i] = (*newBoard + cols * i);
}
```

Here the `newBoard[i]` are getting an offset of the continues block of memory,
so you cannot free more than once at different offsets, you have to free it
**once** at the start of the block.

```
free(newBoard[0]);
free(newBoard);
```

would be correct.

Please don't [cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), this is bad practice. And you should check if
`malloc` returns `NULL`.

I personally think that this is a clever way to do only 2 `malloc`s instead of
`row+1` `malloc`s, but it has downsides, too. You have to be very careful with it. Freeing single blocks of memory that
are not needed is not possible, reallocation of single `newBoard[i]` is also not
possible. You have to have a lot of discipline in order to avoid mistakes like
multiple `free`s, that's why I think that the traditional way of doing, is
better overall. I'd do:

```
for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    newBoard[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof *newBoard[i]);
```

then you can free like you did.

Comment: This was extremely helpful thank you! Sorry for the bad practice, I'm new to c. I appreciate the advice!